# Cannot run hadoop dfs -ls from slave node

Tags: hadoop, configuration, hdfs

Should I be able to run the command:

`hadoop dfs -ls`

from slave node?

Currently I cannot, I get the following error:

**13/11/01 14:58:03 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: ec2-54-200-245-100.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/172.31.17.66:9000. Already tried 0 time(s).
13/11/01 14:58:04 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: ec2-54-200-245-100.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/172.31.17.66:9000. Already tried 1 time(s).
13/11/01 14:58:05 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: ec2-54-200-245-100.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/172.31.17.66:9000. Already tried 2 time(s).
13/11/01 14:58:06 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: ec2-54-200-245-100.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/172.31.17.66:9000. Already tried 3 time(s).
13/11/01 14:58:07 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: ec2-54-200-245-100.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/172.31.17.66:9000. Already tried 4 time(s).
13/11/01 14:58:08 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: ec2-54-200-245-100.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/172.31.17.66:9000. Already tried 5 time(s).
13/11/01 14:58:09 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: ec2-54-200-245-100.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/172.31.17.66:9000. Already tried 6 time(s).
13/11/01 14:58:10 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: ec2-54-200-245-100.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/172.31.17.66:9000. Already tried 7 time(s).
13/11/01 14:58:11 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: ec2-54-200-245-100.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/172.31.17.66:9000. Already tried 8 time(s).
13/11/01 14:58:12 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: ec2-54-200-245-100.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/172.31.17.66:9000. Already tried 9 time(s).
Bad connection to FS. command aborted.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check on your slave nodes the property called `fs.default.name` in core-site.xml and make sure it points to your namenode.

Since you seem to be on EC2 it should be something like

```
<property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://namenode.ec2.demdex.com:9000</value>
</property>
```